# set range of date to display in calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, code-behind

I have this asp.net calendar control:

```
<asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="calendar" SelectionMode="Day" ondayrender="DateRange" />
```

and its code behind:

```
protected void DateRange(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    //do some codes here to set the range of the calendar to display
}
```

I haven't implemented anything to my DateRange cause I don't know the algorithm of it.

If I want my calendar control to display only specific month and days:

Example:
Display only the ranges (July 04, 2015 - March 15, 2016) //Nothing follows

Is it possible to alter the default calendar method to display only the specific months,days above?

Please help, I'm new to calendar event and its built in functions in c#.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx) for that class? It describes the event fairly well.

Comment: I haven't sir, I'm reading it now. Is it possible to display the said ranges in my calendar programatically?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I think it's important you learn to use the documentation when you have a question about how something that's part of the framework works, so I'm not going to directly answer just yet.

Comment: I'll take note of that sir, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change what but only how it is displayed and you can make it unselectable:

```
protected void DateRange(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime rangeStart = new DateTime(2015, 7, 4);
    DateTime rangeEnd   = new DateTime(2016, 3, 15);

    if (e.Day.Date < rangeStart || e.Day.Date > rangeEnd)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the one I've been looking for sir, thank you so much! :) This greatly helps.

Comment: Hmm, one thing in the calendar though,  the month on page load displays the current month today(October). Just want to change the month to (July) when the web page loads.

Comment: `calendar.VisibleDate = new DateTime(2015, 7, 4);`

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano That's really a seperate question. And again, check the documentation first before asking! Don't get in the habit of running to SO every time you have a question, it'll pollute SO and you won't learn nearly as well.